# pythonのNetworkXで日本語が含まれるファイルを読み込みたい

Tags: python, networkx

NetworkXを用いて、日本語ファイル(prn)を読み込もうとしたのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいました。
初歩的な点で申し訳ござませんが、ご助言頂けますと幸いです。

エラー
QT---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f4f3d26af7f2> in <module>()
      2 G=nx.DiGraph()
      3 #エッジ（辺）リストをファイルを読み込んで作成
----> 4 G=nx.read_edgelist("sm10.prn",nodetype=int,create_using=nx.DiGraph())
      5 
      6 

<C:\Users\IWAMOTO MOMOKA\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\decorator.pyc:decorator-gen-703> in read_edgelist(path, comments, delimiter, create_using, nodetype, data, edgetype, encoding)

C:\Users\IWAMOTO MOMOKA\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.pyc in _open_file(func_to_be_decorated, *args, **kwargs)
    238         # Finally, we call the original function, making sure to close the fobj
    239         try:
--> 240             result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
    241         finally:
    242             if close_fobj:

C:\Users\IWAMOTO MOMOKA\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.pyc in read_edgelist(path, comments, delimiter, create_using, nodetype, data, edgetype, encoding)
    367     return parse_edgelist(lines, comments=comments, delimiter=delimiter,
    368                           create_using=create_using, nodetype=nodetype,
--> 369                           data=data)
    370 
    371 

C:\Users\IWAMOTO MOMOKA\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.pyc in parse_edgelist(lines, comments, delimiter, create_using, nodetype, data)
    267             except:
    268                 raise TypeError("Failed to convert nodes %s,%s to type %s."
--> 269                                 % (u, v, nodetype))
    270 
    271         if len(d) == 0 or data is False:

<type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u"Failed to convert nodes \u9d8f,\u305f\u307e\u3054 to type <type 'int'>.", 24, 25, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

UNQT-------------------------------------------------------------

元ファイルおよびコードは以下の通りです。

QT-------------------------------------------------------------

```
鶏      たまご
ごはん  たまご
オムライごはん
チャーハオムライス
にら玉  鶏
```

UNQT-----------------------------------------------------------

QT--------------------------------------------------------------

```
# coding=UTF-8
#関数の宣言
import networkx as nx
import string
import pandas as pd
import collections
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#有向グラフを指定
G=nx.DiGraph()
#エッジ（辺）リストをファイルを読み込んで作成
G=nx.read_edgelist("sm10.prn",nodetype=int,create_using=nx.DiGraph())


#ノード(頂点)数出力
print(nx.number_of_nodes(G))
#エッジ数出力
print(nx.number_of_edges(G))
#ネットワーク基本情報出力
print(nx.info(G))
#次数分布

print(nx.degree_histogram(G))
```

UNQT-----------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1):

**原因判明**
取り敢えずエラーは無くして何かが表示されるところまでは来ました。

既に指摘した2点

- データファイルの encoding を utf-8 に変換すること
- nodetype=int を nodetype=str に変更すること

の他に、**「データファイルの3行目・4行目の文字列が区切られていなくて有効なデータになっていない」** というのが原因でした。質問記事を書いた際の転記ミスかもしれませんが、データを以下のように直したら処理が行われました。

```
鶏         たまご
ごはん     たまご
オムライス ごはん
チャーハン オムライス
にら玉     鶏
```

結果はこんな出力になっています。

```
6
5
Name:
Type: DiGraph
Number of nodes: 6
Number of edges: 5
Average in degree:   0.8333
Average out degree:   0.8333
[0, 2, 4]
```

環境的には Windows10 64bit, Python 3.7.6, NetworkX 2.4, pandas 1.0.1, matplotlib 3.2.0, numpy 1.18.1 を使っています。

---

**以下：当初回答**

単純に、データファイルが UTF-8 ではなく UTF-16 で作られているからでしょう。
データファイルを UTF-8 に変換しておくか、`read_edgelist`呼び出し時に`encoding`を`utf-16`に指定すれば大丈夫だと思われます。

[read_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html)

> read_edgelist(path, comments='#', delimiter=None, create_using=None, nodetype=None, data=True, edgetype=None, encoding='utf-8')

エラーメッセージのコードを見るとUTF-16のコードです。

> ```
> <type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u"Failed to convert nodes \u9d8f,\u305f\u307e\u3054 to type <type 'int'>.", 24, 25, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
> ```

[\u9d8f](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9d8f/index.htm) 鶏
[\u305f](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/305f/index.htm) た
[\u307e](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/307e/index.htm) ま
[\u3054](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3054/index.htm) ご

---

コメントに書かれたエラーの`0x0a`は改行コードなので、普通に文字の一部であり、それがエラーになるのはちょっとおかしい感じです。

それでデータフォーマット関連で検索してみたところでは、以下の記事を見ると `nodetype=int`ではなく `nodetype=str` を指定してみてはどうでしょう。
[Python の NetworkX 入門](https://qiita.com/tomov3/items/64f7315474747fc01a6c)
データの例がこちらで

> ```
> 0 1
> 0 2
> 0 3
> 0 4
>  ：
> ```

プログラム例がこちら

> ```
> # グラフを構築
> G = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', nodetype=int)
> ```

[Pythonでネットワークを分析・可視化しよう！必要手順まとめ](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/91371)
データの例がこちらで

> 実際のデータ: [edgelist.txt](https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/samurai-blog-media/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/edgelist.txt)
>
> ```
> A B
> A C
> A D
> A E
> A F
>  ：
> ```

プログラム例がこちら

> ```
> G = nx.read_edgelist('edgelist.txt', nodetype=str)
> ```

Comment: ご回答頂き有難うございます。encoding="utf-16" を追加したのですが、以下のエラーが出てきてしましました。また、UTF-8のファイルでやった場合も同様に質問と同じエラーが出てきてしまいました。。。。

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 22:

Comment: kunifさん　ご返信遅くなり申し訳ございません。関連サイトまで有難うございます。試しにやってみたいのですが、やはりエラーは治りませんでした。されどご助言頂き有難うございました。

Comment: 駄目ならNetworkXの機能で自動でファイルを読んでデータを作らせるのではなく、自分でファイルを読んでデータを作るとかしてみればどうでしょう？ [NetworkX と PyGraphviz / Gephi で日本語ラベル付きエッジを持つグラフを可視化](https://qiita.com/memakura/items/9d73ac1b422009210629), [\[Python\]NetworkXでQiitaのタグ関係図を描く](https://qiita.com/inoory/items/088f719f2fd9a2ea4ee5), [NetworkXの頂点の書式を設定する](https://analytics-note.xyz/programming/networkx-node-setting/), [networkxで全国名字ネットワークを可視化してみた](https://datumstudio.jp/blog/networkx%E3%81%A7%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E5%90%8D%E5%AD%97%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E5%8F%AF%E8%A6%96%E5%8C%96%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F)

Comment: 有難うございます。試行錯誤してみます。

Comment: 質問記事の範囲内でなら、原因判明してこの回答の最初の方に挿入しました。確認してみてください。

Comment: kunifさん。有難うございます。おっしゃる通り直したところエラーがなくなりました！また、大変申し訳ないのですが、pythonが2.7verであったことも原因だったようです。3.7以降にしたところエラーが解消しました。長らくアドバイス頂き有難うございました。